# Unable to increase screen resolution

Tags: xorg, gui, manjaro, resolution

I am using Manjaro KDE Edition and am unable to increase my screen resolution beyond 960x540. On the login screen (SDDM), the display was at it's full 1080x1920. I have already tried to use `xrandr` and KDE system settings. It seems to be a problem with my user's X server, as when I start `Xorg :1` as a different user, the resolution is the usual 1080x1920.

Please ask for more information if needed.

Here is some information that might be useful, but I doubt it is helpful.

- Before the issue, I was playing a game (via Valve Proton, in low resolution due to performance issues).
- I have tried to install nVidia drivers both before and after issue

Comment: What procedures have you already try to handle your problem?

Comment: Don't know how to resolve the issue myself, but here are a couple of links purporting to resolve it in Manjaro, from a quick search of `linux resolution stuck in 960x540`... [Low resolution on laptop screen](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/low-resolution-on-laptop-screen/41307) and [Resolution problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/dyende/resolution_problem/)